# svm-scale: command not found

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, command-line

I am running a **cpp** code in **xcode** along with **opencv**. Inside the cpp code, there is a **command** line:

```
system("svm-scale -r allrange test_ind>> test_ind_scaled")
```

When i run the code, it's give a error like **svm-scale: command not found**

But when i run this command line (**svm-scale -r allrange test_ind>> test_ind_scaled**) from **terminal**, it's giving **no error**.

Any suggestion how to run this command line from inside the cpp code ?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you run both of this from the same working directory?

Comment: @wdudzik - yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `svm-scale` with its full path. Reading other xcode-related questions hinted that xcode might not use your `PATH` variable, so `system` doesn't know where to look for the specific command.

Comment: While running **svm-scale** with it's full path it's found **svm-scale** but now it's can't open **allrange** file.

Comment: Make sure the path to `allrange` is correct as well. Try using its full path, if it works, then try to find out which directory the program is looking inside.